# Error in implementing onItemSelected() method of Spinner in eclipse

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

```
package com.pro;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public abstract class Bt12 extends Activity implements     OnItemSelectedListener
{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.spinloader);

   final ProgressBar spinner;
    spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    spinner.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }, 4000);

   final Spinner s=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aa=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinlist, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s.setAdapter(aa);

    s.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    s.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                s.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, 5000);

    View iv1;
    iv1 = (View)findViewById(R.id.spinner_image1);
    iv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    View iv2;
    iv2 = (View)findViewById(R.id.spinner_image2);
    iv2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    View iv3;
    iv3 = (View)findViewById(R.id.spinner_image3);
    iv3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    View iv4;
    iv4 = (View)findViewById(R.id.spinner_image4);
    iv4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int pos, long id) {
         Spinner s=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        View st=(View) s.getSelectedItem();
        st.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         s.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }

  /*  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }*/


}
```

is there something wrong?? this shows no error but doesn't work correctly..i trigger this activity using a button and when i click it now..it does nothing but the screen blinks.
is there something wrong?? this shows no error but doesn't work correctly..i trigger this activity using a button and when i click it now..it does nothing but the screen blinks.
is there something wrong?? this shows no error but doesn't work correctly..i trigger this activity using a button and when i click it now..it does nothing but the screen blinks.
is there something wrong?? this shows no error but doesn't work correctly..i trigger this activity using a button and when i click it now..it does nothing but the screen blinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not implement an `onClickListener`?
The `Spinner` class supports this. Then, you can perform any actions in the `onItemClick` method.

Here is a code example of what that looks like:

```
s.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        // Put what you want here
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't even notice that. 
You should probably check out the [Java docs on abstract classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) to avoid a mistake like that in the future.

Comment: @Lady_ari I get this error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner."

Answer (score 0):

try ,

```
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aa=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(youractivity.this, R.array.spinlist, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```